# Locating parent directory using "path.join" not working on Heroku

Tags: express, heroku, path

Here's brief structure of my app

```
  ├── client
  │     └─ build
  │          └─ index.html
  │
  │
  ├── server
  │     └─ index.js
```

code for production to hot on Heroku below:

```
// index.js

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {

  // app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "..", "client/build"))); // not working
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "/../client/build"))); // not working


  app.get("*", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "/../client/build", "index.html")); // not working
  });
}
```

The error from Heroku below:

[image]

As the error log tells that somehow **path.join(__dirname, "/../client/build")** does not point client directory that is outside of server directory (root), instead it's just locating same *server* directory like /server/client which is wrong path and does not even exist as the error above shows.

**How to locate 'clinet/build/' ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually figured out.

Due to TypeScript dist directory that was built and index.js nested inside so.

Instead of server/index.js it was actually server/dist/index.js as it turned out one level deeper.

Therefore, to reach out to root directory, it must be '/../../' rather than '/../'

Working code below:

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {

  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "/../../client/build")));

  app.get("*", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "/../../client/build", "index.html"));
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand what you are trying to do but try this hope it works for you

```
  app.use(express.static('client/build'));
    app.get('*',(req,res)=>{
        res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname,'client','build','index.html'))
    })
```